# Is it better to use different dimens values according to the screen density or to the screen size?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support, screen-density

I have a TextView in a ConstraintLayout with `layout_marginTop=@margindimen` and `layout_marginBottom=@margindimen` attributes. As there are different screen sizes, the margin value should change according to the specific screen. This is why I have created in dimens folder dimens/dimens.xml(small), dimens/dimens.xml(normal), dimens/dimens.xml(large)... and set the value of "margindimen" in each screen size dimens file. I have seen that a 480x854px device and a 720x1080px device are both from dimens(normal) so there is a huge difference of size between those devices. This is why I was wondering if it was better to make different values according to the screen density and not according to de screen size: dimens/dimens.xml(ldpi), dimens/dimens.xml(hdpi), dimens/dimens.xml(xhdpi)...

If making different values according to the screen density will make me have the same problem, how could I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create different `dimens` files with `smallest-width` selection. This allows you to identify **small/normal/big** screen.

Take a look at this [guideline](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/support-different-screen-sizes#smallest-width). There talking more about column optimization, but you also may change spaces this way.

Your files will looks like this:

[image]

Also take care about portrait/landscape orientation, because in rotation case smallest-width will be changed.

Comment: If my Layout margins are Top margin and Bottom margin (dependent of the screen height) why should I use `smallest-width` and not something like `smallest-height`?

Comment: You can use it, you're right :) Depends on case.

Comment: The problem is that `smallest-height` doesn't exist, I have only found `smallest-width` attribute...

Comment: Ups, sorry, my mistake (saw `screen-height` and thinking about `smallest-height`). But I think `smallest-width` also will make a deal